# How can I count the total number of inputs with values on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm hoping for a super simple validation script that matches total inputs on a form to total inputs with values on a form.  Can you help explain why the following doesn't work, and suggest a working solution?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d7DDu/

Fill out one or more of the inputs and click "submit".  I want to see the number of filled out inputs as the result.  So far it only shows `0`.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="one">
<input type="text" name="two">
<input type="text" name="three">
<textarea name="four"></textarea>
<button id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
<div id="count"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#btn-submit').bind('click', function() {
    var filledInputs = $(':input[value]').length;
    $('#count').html(filledInputs);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[value]` refers to the value *attribute*, which is very different to the value *property*.

The property is updated as you type, the attribute stays the same. This means you can do `elem.value = elem.getAttribute("value")` to "reset" a form element, by the way.

Personally, I'd do something like this:

```
var filledInputs = $(':input').filter(function() {return !!this.value;}).length;
```

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thanks - of course normally I'd use `document.querySelectorAll("input,textarea")` in place of the jQuery selector XD

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, if I wanted to do the inverse of the above (filter out inputs with values, leaving only the empty ones), what would that filter function look like?

Comment: Thanks.  For others using this in the future... I did notice that this does not exclude inputs with merely a ` ` (space).  Any idea how to sneak a trim into there?

Comment: `return !!this.value.replace(/^ +/,'')`

Comment: thanks. what if i want to refer to td something like 'td amount class="editable-col" contenteditable="true" ' '/td'   ...  var filledInputs = $('editable-col').filter(function() {return !!this.value.replace(/^ +/,'')}).length;  does not work

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/d7DDu/1/

```
$('#btn-submit').bind('click', function() {
    var x = 0;
    $(':input').each(function(){
        if(this.value.length > 0){ x++; };
    });
    $('#count').html(x);
});
```